# Slow performance after switching to HEREMap premium SDK

Tags: android, react-native, here-api

I am facing performance issues with HEREMap Premium Android SDK in my react-native project. Previously I was using free version of HEREMap, and my map view was performing very well. But once I switched to Premium SDK, view rendering became very slow.

Following were the only changes I did for premium SDK integration,

1. Invoke `setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath` api before `MapEngine.getInstance().init`
2. Update licence key information in app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Am I missing something? please help.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath for the first time it will take longer time to download all the map data. So this is expected behaviour for the first time after you have changed to Premium SDK. Also, map loading time depends on your network connection as well. In general, Here recommends having offline map downloaded already in your app.

Edit: You can also try removing setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath() but then you can to change your manifest file accordingly. Refer "Using a Shared Disk Cache with the Map Service" section in  https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-service.html

```
<service
  android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
  android:label="HereMapService"
  android:process="global.Here.Map.Service.v3"
  android:exported="true" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService.v3" >
    </action>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer... But the performance is slow even after the first time load... AFIK, in starer kit sdk am able to use MapView without calling setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath. But in premium SDK setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath() is mandatory. 

Is there a way where I can render the map without using setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath. As there isn't much changes I did (while switching to premium) am struck without any clue here...

Comment: Edit the answer on how you can remove the setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath()

Comment: I updated as suggested in the edit, but it didn't resolve my issue. What else might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and found a solution eventually. The important thing is to use the AndroidXMapFragment in the view's layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        class="com.here.android.mpa.mapping.AndroidXMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

and to inflate it in the view using an activity reference that I passed to the view's constructor:

```
mapLayout = (FrameLayout) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_layout, null);
```

Afterwards, the map fragment can be fetched and initialized:

```
mapFragment = (AndroidXMapFragment) activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
```

Comment: How did you get activity.getSupportFragmentManager() to work? That method doesn't seem to be accessible off of the activity from ReactContext.

Comment: I passed the activity as a parameter for the views constructor.